# R: find the year when one value is higher then other by category

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing location (`loc`), distance within location (`dist`), value (`cumRate`), and year (`year`) columns.

I would like to compare rates between distances, identify which one is higher and find a year, when rates in one zone become higher then in another, as shown below (in year 2, the distance "100" was higher then the distance "npr")

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

This seems easy, but I don't really know where to start... Thank you for your suggestions!

---

Dummy data:

```
loc = rep(c("a","b"), each = 6)
dist = rep(c("npr", "100", "npr", "100"), each = 3)
cumRate = c(0,0,4,0,1,2,0,0,1,3,5,7)
year = rep(c(1,2,3), 4)

df = data.frame(loc, dist, cumRate, year)



       loc dist cumRate year
1    a  npr       0    1
2    a  npr       0    2
3    a  npr       4    3
4    a  100       0    1
5    a  100       1    2
6    a  100       2    3
7    b  npr       0    1
8    b  npr       0    2
9    b  npr       1    3
10   b  100       3    1
11   b  100       5    2
12   b  100       7    3
```

---

Plot data

```
windows()
ggplot(df, aes(x = year,
               y = cumRate,
               fill = dist,
               colour = dist)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(.~ loc)
```

### [image]

Desired output

```
outDf

  loc dist  year
   a  100       2
   b  100       1
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more. What is your expected outcome? The years with the max difference? So, year 2 when 100 is higher, and year 3 when npr is higher?

Comment: @Anonymouscoward, thank you for your suggestion, I added expected output to my question. I want to compare values between two dist ("npr", "100") and identify the year when this happens for the first time. So, for location "a", the rate was higher in dist "100" than in dist "npr" in year 2. In location "b",  rate in dist "100" was higher than in dist "npr" in year 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method without spreading:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(loc, year) %>%
    filter(max(cumRate) != min(cumRate)) %>%
    arrange(loc, year, desc(cumRate)) %>%
    group_by(loc) %>%
    slice(1)
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   loc [2]
#      loc   dist cumRate  year
#   <fctr> <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      a    100       1     2
# 2      b    100       3     1
```

First we remove years where there is no variation in `cumRate`, then we sort the data by location, year, and descending cum rate, and take the first row within each location.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need to unpivot the `dist` column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  spread(dist, cumRate) %>%
  mutate(higher_dist = case_when(
    `100` > npr ~ '100',
    npr > `100` ~ 'npr',
    TRUE ~ 'equal')
  ) %>%
  filter(npr != `100`) %>%
  group_by(loc) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  slice(1)

  loc    year `100`   npr higher_dist
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1 a         2     1     0 100        
2 b         1     3     0 100
```

Comment: thank you @zack, I like you approach. But I don't understand, if in the year 1 the npr and "100" values are the same, why the "higher_dist" is "npr"? I also need to get back only the first year when the one of values in higher than another

Comment: Just add a `filter(npr != \`100\`)` before the mutate to remove rows where they are the same.

Comment: @maycca, that was just because of how the `if_else` statement was designed. It's now updated to reflect cases of equality. Also updated to select first row.

Comment: @Gregor Just noticed that too when checking out your solution - not sure how i missed it originally (actually I think OP modified post after I answered it). Added a `group_by` statement to should take care of it, thanks.